How to backup folder before releasing the new build to on-premise server with copyfiletask@2 specific format in Azure CI/CD Pipeline
Folder path : D:\Applications\wwwroot\Example
Backup path : D:\Applications\test-backup\Eample-backup\YYYY\DDMMYYYY
How to archive above using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops&tabs=yaml task?
Final output:
Folder path : D:\Applications\wwwroot\Example
Backup path : D:\Applications\test-backup\Eample-backup\2024\11062024

As suggested in my answer below, you can use the date related command to get the current date with the specified formats, and then use the logging command SetVariable to map the values as pipeline variables. By this way, the subsequent tasks (include the CopyFiles@2 task) can use the variables as normal. Have you tried this way? Does it work for you? @RahulKumarSurati

You can try like as below in your pipeine:

Get the current year and date with the specified format. Below is the commands in Bash.
year=$(date '+%Y')
echo $year
date=$(date '+%d%m%Y')
echo $date


Use the logging command SetVariable to map the values of year and date as two pipeline variables so that the subsequent CopyFiles@2 task can use the values.
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=year;]$year"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=date;]$date"


Then on the CopyFiles@2 task, you can use the pipeline variables.


See below pipeline YAML as reference.
steps:
. . .

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Get Date'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      year=$(date '+%Y')
      echo $year
      date=$(date '+%d%m%Y')
      echo $date
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=year;]$year"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=date;]$date"

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Backup Folder'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'D:/Applications/wwwroot/Example'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: 'D:/Applications/test-backup/Eample-backup/$(year)/$(date)'

If you want to use PowerShell instead of Bash to get the date, the YAML looks like below.
steps:
. . .

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Get Date'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      $year = Get-Date -Format "yyyy"
      Write-Host $year
      $date = Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy"
      Write-Host $date
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=year;]$year"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=date;]$date"

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Backup Folder'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'D:/Applications/wwwroot/Example'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: 'D:/Applications/test-backup/Eample-backup/$(year)/$(date)'




@RahulKumarSurati, No problem, and please go ahead to try as my suggestions.
